# Sass @extend base/default without also extending pseudo-classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors, extend, sass

I know I can @extend .foo:hover, but is there a way to @extend the .foobar base/default properties without also extending the definitions for pseudo-classes like :hover, :active, etc?

**For example**, how would I change the following such that .foobar extends only .foo's default state?

```
.foo {
    & {
         color:blue;
    }
    &:hover {
         background-color: black;
    }
}

.foobar {
     @extend .foo;
     &:hover {
          //As is, I have to override. Any better way?
          background-color: transparent;
     }
}
```

(If there is no way to do this with Sass, is there a preferred way to achieve the same effect?)

Comment: @feeela Sass extends are all or nothing.  It is not possible to extend only part of a selector, you must rethink how your selectors are written if that's what you want.

Answer (score 10):

You have to rewrite your selectors in such a way that you only extend exactly the part you want:

```
%foo {
    color:blue;
}

.foo {
    @extend %foo;

    &:hover {
         background-color: black;
    }
}

.foobar {
    @extend %foo;

    &:hover {
         background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

However, depending on how you are going to be extending/reusing your .foo class, the new @content directive might be the better way to go.

```
@mixin foo {
    color: blue;

    &:hover {
        @content;
    }
}

.foo {
    @include foo {
        background-color: black;
    }
}

.foobar {
    @include foo {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? I have the same problem as the OP and only want to extend the base class, but SASS does a whole lot of additional vodoo. Reading through the documentation of \@content I can't see any relations to \@extend…

Comment: @feeela I've rephrased the answer.  `@content` has nothing to do with `@extend`, but there are times that using a content aware mixin would produce a more compact results.